# Limitations of parallelizing heterogeneous tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I was reading Java Concurrency in Practice and a paragraph came across which said something like this:-

> Under *6.3.4 Limitations of parallelizing heterogeneous tasks*
>
> A further problem with dividing heterogeneous tasks among multiple workers
> is that the tasks may have disparate sizes. If you divide tasks A and B between
> two workers but A takes ten times as long as B, you’ve only speeded up the total
> process by 9%. Finally, **dividing a task among multiple workers always involves
> some amount of coordination overhead; for the division to be worthwhile, this
> overhead must be more than compensated by productivity improvements due to
> parallelism**.

Now if you go through the bold part, is it correct to say that worker threads' co-ordination overhead must be more than the performance improvement I achieve using parallelism of threads?

Could some one please help me understand it?

Comment: Other way around. It must be less than the performance gain. Part of me thinks this might be a fit for ELU...

Comment: Might be migrated to http://ell.stackexchange.com/ ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the bolded bit changes the meaning of the sentence quite significantly:

> Finally, dividing a task among multiple workers always involves some amount of coordination overhead; for the division to be worthwhile, this overhead must be **more than compensated** by productivity improvements due to parallelism.

If that was simply "must be more than the productivity improvements..." then you would be right. What the above is saying is that the performance penalty you incur by dividing the tasks among your worker threads (the overhead), must be **less** than the performance increase you gain by doing it at all.

For instance, if your overhead is 10 seconds and your performance gain is only 5 seconds, then parallelising the operation has actually *decreased* your overall performance. If your overhead is 10 seconds but the performance gain is 50 seconds, you've ended up with a 40 second reduction in the overall execution time (i.e. an improvement).

Another way of saying it would be "...this overhead must be offset by the productivity improvements due to parallelism.".

Comment: I think it's also important to note that **isolated timing** isn't the only metric to take into account. As dividing might also require more CPU clocks, memory and even I/O processing (if caching intermediate state to make parallel data fit in memory). When running in isolation, your tasks don't have to fight in concurrency with machine resource usage of other application processes.

Comment: @LoganMzz You're absolutely right - I just made up some simple numbers on the spot to get the point across, I wasn't trying to imply that parallelising code is in any way a simple operation :)

Comment: I think your answer is perfect like this, simple, clear and demonstrating against the question. I would just like to add precision to Java developer working with parallel task as concurrency reside on more than just resource access synchronization. And note also addresses particularly to _Java Concurrency in Practice_ readers.

Comment: It is worth noting that the overhead of managing each bit of parallel work (creation of  unit-of-parallel-work, atomic insertion into work list, pulling work out of work list, loading machine registers, destroying the unit of work, going back to the scheduler to get another unit of work,) can actually be surprisingly more expensive than you might expect.   In practice, this means that you generally cannot put "just a few statements" into a parallel unit and come out ahead.  ...

Comment: ... People are often suprised by how much work they do have to put in a parallel grain to make it efficient.  Parallel execution libraries particularly aggravate this.   It is best when the compiler knows about the parallelism and and can maximally weave these management bits into the compiled code to keep the overhead low.    I don't know if the Java compiler/JIT actually does this.   It is important enough so that  we designed a programming language to help us achieve that effect.  (If you want to know more, check out PARLANSE via my user page).